# How to turn two VARCHAR2 lists into an associative array?

Tags: plsql

I'm looking for a way to turn two VARCHAR2 lists into an associative array... More specifically, a `table of varchar2(30) index by varchar2(30)`. For example:

```
v_list1 sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list('A', 'B', 'C');
v_list2 sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list('1', '2', '3');

(...)

v_result := SomeFunction(v_list1, v_list2);

-- v_result above should be such that:

-- v_result('A') = '1'
-- v_result('B') = '2'
-- v_result('C') = '3'
```

In other words, the result should be an associative array where each element in list1 indexes the corresponding element in list2.

Here's what I've tried:

```
declare
  type t_associative_vc2 is table of varchar2(30) index by varchar2(30);
  v_list1 sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list('A', 'B', 'C');
  v_list2 sys.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list('1', '2', '3');

  v_zipped t_associative_vc2;
  v_index  varchar2(30);

  -- Purpose: turn p_list1 and p_list2 into an associative VARCHAR2 to VARCHAR2 array
  -- Elements of p_list1 will index those of p_list2
  function zip(p_list1 sys.odcivarchar2list, p_list2 sys.odcivarchar2list) return t_associative_vc2 is
    v_result t_associative_vc2;
  begin
    for i in p_list1.first .. p_list1.last loop
      v_result(p_list1(i)) := p_list2(i);
    end loop;
    return v_result;
  end;
begin
  -- Zip both lists
  v_zipped := zip(v_list1, v_list2);
  -- Print the associative array's keys and values
  v_index := v_zipped.first;
  while v_index is not null loop
    dbms_output.put_line(v_index || ' --> ' || v_zipped(v_index));
    v_index := v_zipped.next(v_index);
  end loop;
end;
```

Which produces the following output:

```
A --> 1
B --> 2
C --> 3
```

So far, so good, it seems...

My question, though, is: am I doing this correctly? I ask because I'm not sure if it's "fine" to use the index in `p_list1` to index `p_list2`.

My goal is, essentially, to populate `v_zipped` above with the pairs: ('A','1'), ('B','2') and ('C','3').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you had built will work fine as long as the values in `v_list1` are distinct.  If they are for example set up like this:

```
v_list1    SYS.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list ('A', 'B', 'C', 'A');
v_list2    SYS.odcivarchar2list := sys.odcivarchar2list ('1', '2', '3', '4');
```

Then the output will be

```
A --> 4
B --> 2
C --> 3
```

That is fine as long as that is what you are expecting.

Another option is to create a record type that contains both string values and store that as a table. This will allow for duplicate "keys" that may be a problem with your first solution.

```
DECLARE
    TYPE two_strings_rec IS RECORD
    (
        val1    VARCHAR2 (30),
        val2    VARCHAR2 (30)
    );

    TYPE two_strings_t IS TABLE OF two_strings_rec;

    v_list1         SYS.odcivarchar2list
                        := sys.odcivarchar2list ('A',
                                                 'B',
                                                 'C',
                                                 'A');
    v_list2         SYS.odcivarchar2list
                        := sys.odcivarchar2list ('1',
                                                 '2',
                                                 '3',
                                                 '4');
    l_two_strings   two_strings_t := two_strings_t ();
BEGIN
    l_two_strings.EXTEND (LEAST (v_list1.COUNT, v_list2.COUNT));

    FOR i IN 1 .. l_two_strings.COUNT
    LOOP
        l_two_strings (i) := two_strings_rec (v_list1 (i), v_list2 (i));
    END LOOP;

    FOR i IN 1 .. l_two_strings.COUNT
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_two_strings (i).val1 || ' --> ' || l_two_strings (i).val2);
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Output

```
A --> 1
B --> 2
C --> 3
A --> 4
```